# Is it a good idea to replace parent class with test stub in unit tests?

Tags: php, unit-testing, yii

**tl;dr**

As I said in the title, if the class under test is a wrapper over the library class, which maybe uses a lot of static dependencies and/or possibly a database connection, *is this a best practice to replace this parent class with a hand-written stub*?

**Details**

Context is a unit test suite for widget toolkit for Yii PHP web framework. System under test is a 12k lines of legacy PHP 5.3 code and first I want to write a characterization tests, because auto-refactoring for PHP sucks pretty badly even in phpStorm. I'm particularly interested in testing extenders of `CWidget` class.

It's a PHP, so I can just `require_once` any combination of source files for each of my unit tests, so constructing a completely fake environment is not a problem.

I have a copies of Martin Fowler's *Refactoring* and Michael Feather's *Working Effectively with Legacy Code*, so, if there is, maybe someone can point me to exact techniques, because it seems that I am overlooking something for sure.

Comment: The answer to the "tl;dr" part is definitely no: it's not a best practice. If the parent class is something that you can meaningfully stub out, then you shouldn't be using inheritance/is-a for it. (Composition/has-a would be more appropriate.) But the "Details" part makes this a more complicated question. Best practices for dealing with legacy code are not always unqualified best practices.